# Refreshing dataframe asynchronously

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to refresh certain lookup tables (stored as temp tables on data frames) while the main code keeps processing data.

Currently i have implemented Scala Future call for perpetually refreshing the tables (with a sleep timer of 5 minutes or so) such that the lookup tables are synchronized.

The logic almost works, but I am concerned on -

1. whether this is the right way of achieving the end goal i am looking
   for
2. what other approach can be taken up for achieving this !!!

[EDIT]
Bump, anyone !!! Help needed here...